# Обновление ASp.Net MVC 4 to MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

У меня VS Version 12.0.21005 REL.

Проекты могу создавать asp.net mvc 4, что мне нужно установить/обновить чтобы я мог создавать проекты asp.net mvc5 and web api 2?

Answer (score 2):

Все это можно сделать через менеджер пакетов "NuGet", установив следующие пакеты

1. **Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 5.2.2**,
2. **Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi**

Answer (score 1):

Можно скачать установщик в официальном сайте
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/11/18/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2013-1-for-visual-studio-2012/